# form not following .live() bind

Tags: forms, jquery

I have a form that has been generated after the document was loaded. and I am trying to stop submission with a `return false;` but it does not stop the form from reloading the document. here is my code:

```
$('#name-update.updateAcct').live('submit', function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
    console.log(action);
    switch(action){
        case "name":
            var firstName = $(this).children('input#contct_firstName').val();
            var lastName = $(this).children('input#contct_lastName').val();
            console.log(firstName+" "+lastname);
            break;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I have no idea why this statement isn't stopping the form.

Comment: Please add the HTML for your form.  Also, you can try $(...).live('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }); instead of return false;

Comment: Is the handler being called at all? Try throwing an alert in there or logging to the console in the first line of the function and see what happens.

Comment: Which browser? In IE<8 console.log do not work.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov had the right answer. I missed a capital 'N' on the variable in the console statement. But now the name variables return `undefined` in the console.

Comment: @sightofnick, simply use `$('#contct_firstName').val();` as shown in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
console.log(firstName+" "+lastname);
```

`lastname` doesn't exist (it should be `lastName`) => a javascript error is thrown => the `.live` function never has time to `return false` => the form submits normally.

As far as fetching those names are concerned I see that you are using id selectors and because ids in HTML should be unique you could simplify your life like this:

```
var firstName = $('#contct_firstName').val();
var lastName = $('#contct_lastName').val();
```

or:

```
var firstName = $('input#contct_firstName', this).val();
var lastName = $('input#contct_lastName', this).val();
```

but honestly, the shorter a code is, the smaller the probability of making errors are.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `event.preventDefault();` to the top of your observer:

```
$('#name-update.updateAcct').live('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // stop default form submission
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
    console.log(action);
    switch(action){
        case "name":
            var firstName = $(this).children('input#contct_firstName').val();
            var lastName = $(this).children('input#contct_lastName').val();
            console.log(firstName+" "+lastName);
            break;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yep just how I put it - you pass the event into the observer's function and then prevent the default behavior before doing any custom logic.